# Error in as.double(y) : cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'double' in ggplot command in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, error-handling, double, environment

I am trying to make a plot between two different variables (RodC independent varaible and TickPrev dependent varaible) using the ggplot command. I have the following packages installed: pacman, party, rio, tidyverse,dplyr,MASS.

```
gg1314 <- ggplot(df1314, aes(RodC, TickPrev, color=YearS)) +
  geom_jitter() + 
  labs(title = "Tick Prevalence vs Captured Rodents 2013-2014", 
       x="Tick Prevalence (%)", 
       y="Nº of Captured Rodents") + 
  scale_color_discrete(name="YearSeason")
```

The code above worked perfectly fine, but when I deleted a few rows to conduct a similar analysis with the same variables, the code start to give the following error:

```
ggNBS <- ggplot(dfNBS, aes(RodC, TickPrev, colors=Year)) + 
  geom_jitter() + 
  labs(title = "Tick Prevalence vs Captured Rodents NBS", 
       x="Tick prevalence (%)", 
       y="Nº of captured rodents") + 
  scale_color_discrete(name="Year")
```

> Error in as.double(y) :    cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector
> of type 'double'

The only difference between the dataframes is that I eliminated some rows. But the variables remained the same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GqQa.png)

How can I solve this.
Thank you very much

Image from df1314. dfNBS is the same, but in the MiceS and YearS it only contains information that had NBS or NBS2.

Comment: There is `YearS` in the first case and `Year` in the second case whereas you said the variables remained the same. It would be better if you add a reproducible example in your post with examples of your dataframes, without this it is hard to find the problem

Comment: Thanks but it is still hard with a screenshot to reproduce your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. We would better need you to add to your post the output of `dput(head(df1314))` and `dput(head(dfBNS))`. It should be something like `df1314=structure(...)` Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I was also using %>% plot() so that the plot of the graphic was done right way. After removing that line it solved the problem. :) Thank you for the help.
However now, the plot doens't present colors, all the points are black and shouldn't be.